# Почему названия картинок не доходят до бд?

Tags: laravel

Картинка загружается на сервер, но поле `image` в базе данных не обновляется. Остальные поля обновляются

````
$image = null;
        if($request->file('image')!= null){
            $image = $request->file('image')->store('postImage');
        }
        
        $post->update(array_merge($request->all(), [
            'published_by' => $request->has('published_by'),
            'image' => $image
        ]));
        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index')->with('success', 'Post updated');   ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Распространённая причина в том, что в модели Post в переменной fillable не указано поле image.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне использовать эти картинки в шаблоне?

Comment: В шаблонах использование картинок осуществляется через помощника asset. Но там еще есть нюансы в зависимости от диска, который вы выбрали для хранения своих ресурсов. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem